# Add UITabBar to existing application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uitabbarcontroller

I have fully developed application. I have to implement `UITabBar` into the application, but not in appdelegate, but in some other view & I have to use it for all other views leaving Appdelegate & 1st view after appdelegate.

Can anybody tell me the best way 2 do it?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you already have a `UINavigationController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use active view controller concept here, just fetch active view controller from UIApplication and perform the action.

Comment: Actually my problem is that i have splash screen & login page and i am showing those pages using navigation controller of App delegate. But In appDelegate i also want to use TabBarController Which will be shown after Login page.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to push a `UITabBarController`. For example you can do something like

```
UITabBarController *tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

Controller1 *controller = [[Controller1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Controller1" bundle:nil];

Controller2 *controller = [[Controller2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Controller2" bundle:nil];

Controller3 *controller = [[Controller3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Controller3" bundle:nil];

tabController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:controller1,controller2,controller3,nil];

[controller1 release];
[controller2 release];
[controller3 release];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];
```

Check the reference: [UITabBarController](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=uitabbarcontroller&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html&ei=CWr3TpaMBaaA4gT54PGSCA&usg=AFQjCNEOs06bJBCSzFp6svVxxw1fXjv_Ig&sig2=R-UaK83L21ouYdPwwA6ngw)